# Fetched JSON is not populated in Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using a Model like this:

```
var SidebarCategory = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'sidebar',
    defaults : {
        title  : '',
        items: ''
    }
});
```

And fetching this JSON via GET:

```
{"id":"foo","title":"TITLE","items":"bar baz"}
```

But the Model itself does not take the incoming data.

```
var foo = new SidebarCategory({id: 'foo'});
foo.fetch();

console.log(foo.toJSON());
```

Just taking the id and ignore the rest.

Did I miss something?
What could be the problem?

Comment: Try using the chrome tools or firebug. Both have a network tab, where you can find the actual ajax request, that was made. You can then see if the request was correct and if the response was correct. If both were correct, there is some problem with the initialization. If request was wrong, you can investigate this, if response was bad, you can investigate the server side. but you need to distinguish that first.

Comment: The above mentioned Json is the one that comes back via GET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @CD pointed it out , the `fetch` is asynchronous so you have 2 options for a call back like this :

```
foo.fetch({
success : function(data){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
});
```

OR

```
foo.fetch();

foo.on('reset',function(data){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
},this);
```

You could use either one of the above to deal with the asynchronous call.

Answer (score 3):

[`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) performs an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request, so you should pass [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) a success callback:

```
foo.fetch({
   success: function(){
       console.log(foo.toJSON());  
   }
});
```

Comment: Well, I guess I need some coffee. Right - the AJAX was done after console.log ... That was silly from me.